# Why does recursive Dispatch.main.async take longer and longer?

Tags: recursion, swiftui, dispatch

So I have this recursive function in SwiftUI. Each iteration takes on average 50 ms on a late model iPhone. The whole thing will take a minute or so. When the user kicks it off he expects this and has nothing else to do in the app until the exit condition is reached and it is done. But of course I want it to finish as soon as possible and I want the user to be able to abort it early if he becomes impatient. Also after each iteration it updates a line chart to show its progress to the user. For speed, I’m running it on the main thread like this:

```
.onChange(of: kickItOff) { value in
    recursiveFunction()
}

func recursiveFunction() {
    Dispatch.main.async() {
        step1()
        step2()
        step3()
        if !exit {
            recursiveFunction()
        }
    }
}
```

Each step in an iteration and the iterations themselves must execute serially.

This runs fast and the UI is not blocked. Just one problem.
Each time it is kicked off it takes longer and longer to finish. The 4th run takes twice as long as the 1st.

I profiled it with the signpost instrument and can see that each step in the recursive function does not change duration from iteration to iteration. It is the time gap between iterations that increases.

Does anyone know why this is happening and hopefully have a solution?

Comment: Can you deploy for iOS15? You could try using "async/await".

Comment: Is the increase in the delay linear? Or does it top off at some point?

Comment: [Meet async await](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10132) it is available `@available(macOS 10.15, iOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, tvOS 13.0, *)`

Comment: It seems to be linear and continuing. 
I will look at async/await. Will it still run each iteration serially? I would still like to understand what is happening above. Thanks

Comment: Between 2 recursion, do you stop it by setting exit ? If not , you just start a other async which will have to share time with the previous running. If not can you be more precise in the execution flow ?

Comment: Pitt Xav, exit is updated inside step3(). Does that answer your question?

Comment: And actually the ‘if !exit{} is at the end of step3(), just after exit is updated.

Answer (score 0):

DispatchQueue.main is a serial queue. The async call never returns and recursiveFunction effectively blocks the main queue. If you are subsequently setting exit on the main queue, that will never be executed.